# Integral of squared Hypergeometric Function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to integrate the following

$\int_{0}^{1} {_2{F}_1}\big(-n,1+2m+n,1+m,1-z\big)^2 dz$,

where $m\in\Bbb Z$ and $n\in\Bbb Z$ with $m>0$, $n\geq 0$.

(Basically I want to normalise the function). I am getting this as a part of an effort to find some uniform large approximation for a certain associated Legendre polynomial (in case people are wondering whether it is homework).

I know that

$\int_{0}^{1} (z(1-z))^m {_2{F}_1}\big(-n,1+2m+n,1+m,1-z\big)^2 dz$,

is integrable, under the same conditions, and gives

$\frac{n! \Gamma (m+1)^2 \Gamma (m+n+1) \Gamma (2 m+2 n+1)}{2\Gamma (m+n+1) \Gamma (2 m+n+1) \Gamma (2 m+2 n+2)}\quad\;{_2{F}_1}\big(0, 1 + 2 m + 2 n, 2 m + 2 + 2 n, 1\big)$.

The above is a table integral from I. S. Gradshteyn and I. M. Ryzhik 8th edition (doesn't appear in the 7th)

I welcome any hints or suggestions.

Comment: I can help with the Mathjax integers. Which one do you want, $$m,n\in \Bbb Z$$ Or $$m,n\in\Bbb N$$

Comment: @clathratus the first one, but isn't that just a normal $Z$ ?

Comment: You can see how someone else created a formula by right-clicking on it and selecting "Show Math As > TeX commands". In this case, you well see `\Bbb Z`. the "\Bbb" is just an abbreviation for "\mathbb", and you will note that the { } are not needed if you are only applying the operation to a single character (though a space is needed to allow it to recognize where the operation name ends and the target begins). "\Bbb Z" is the same as "\mathbb{Z}".

Comment: As Paul said, $\Bbb Z$ is made by "\Bbb Z". Same thing with $\Bbb N$: "\Bbb N". hell, you could even do $\Bbb H$

Comment: Thank you people!